# I want to hide a DIV?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I am jQuery to use a Div as a dialog, But before the dialog is called the Div shows at the bottom of my Screen.

How can i hide this div?

```
<div id = "PrintDialog" title="Warning">
        <p>Once you print, no changes may be made to this contract. Are you sure you want to print?</p>
        <input type="button" value="Print" id="btnDialogPrint" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnDialogCancel" />
        </div>
```

I want to still use the Div, just not have it displayed unless its the dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `style="display: none;"` to the `div` like this:

```
<div id="PrintDialog" title="Warning" style="display: none;">
```

When the page loads, this prevents the div from being showed. jQuery will still show the dialog when you want it.

Comment: You're thinking of visibility hidden, which is usually not desired as it keeps the empty space.

Comment: There was no hidden, but with none this works great thanks. +1 and accepted.

Comment: And i don't think you need the ; Mine is running with out it :)

Comment: @Pomster It's not necessary, just as the space between `display:` and `none`. In my opinion it's proper to do.

Comment: @pomster you will need it for multiple items. It is best to get into the habit of always ending them with a semicolon

Answer (score 3):

Use css : style="display:none"

```
<div id = "PrintDialog" title="Warning" style="display:none">
```

or use following jquery code

```
$('#PrintDialog').hide()
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add class "hidden" to your  and remove it when you want to show it as a dailog

`<div id = "PrintDialog" title="Warning" class="hidden">`

CSS for hidden: `.hidden { display: none; }`

Answer (score 2):

Add style="display: none;" or add to your CSS class next code

```
#PrintDialog
{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Or, even better, define CSS rule `.hidden { display: none; }` and assign this class to the div

Comment: @JakubKonecki - Or even do it semantically with the HTML5 `hidden` attribute. Then, for backward compatibility add the CSS rule `[hidden] { display:none; }`

Answer (score 2):

1. using css (if you want init dialog later):
    <style type="text/css">
      #PrintDialog{display:none;}
    </style>
2. Using jQuery UI you just need to initialize dialog after page loaded:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $("#PrintDialog").dialog({ <some arguments such as title and so on> });
    });
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery you just add `$("#PrintDialog").hide();` in your code.

Comment: This could cause flicker during the page rendering and requires javascript to run. Pure CSS solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built in [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method.

i.e.

```
$('#PrintDialog').hide();
```

Comment: This could cause flicker during the page rendering and requires javascript to run. Pure CSS solution is better.

Comment: Considering the already made usage of jQuery, this method allows re-stating the display style to it's original state with .show(); and CSS is not applicable as there is a conditional change here, that needs to be invoked programmability.

Comment: If you use javascript to hide the div you could still see it for brief moment before your js executes. This depends on the amount of js that is executed before your `.hide()` method kicks in.

Comment: true, but still the most practical solution for programatically hiding an element with client side code. Perhaps `document.getElementById('PrintDialog').style.display == "none"`